# Why Segmentation fault in this program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
int *A=NULL; 
*A=12; 
printf("The value of the ponter A is=%d",*A); 
}
```

#### Segmentation error is comming for this programm

Comment: What behaviour did you *expect*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think that misunderstanding comes from the C syntax. It may be misleading for someone not so familiar with pointers. C allows you to declare pointers on `type *var` syntax when it would be more easily understood if written as `type* var` or `type * var`. The first way makes someone unfamiliar with C pointers think you're declaring some `*A` as int instead of declaring a `int *` type.
Maybe this guy was expecting `*A` to behave as an int.

Answer (score 3):

Dereferncing a `NULL` pointer is `undefined behaviour`

```
    int *A=NULL; // creating a pointer to int and setting it to NULL
                 //means it points to nothing
    *A=12; // Now you try to dereference it so it's giving seg fault.
```

One more thing it `int *A` is not `NULL` pointer still assiging a value directly to the pointer is invalid means,

```
int *A ;
*A=12; // It's invalid too
```

You should try this :

```
int a=12;
int *A ;
A=&a; // assign later or you can so it in initialization
```

EDIT : ISO c99 standard : Ponted out in last line of the given paragraph

6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators
Constraints

```
4    The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function,

 the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue 

    designating the object. If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to type’’, the result has 

type ‘‘type’’. If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the 

unary * operator is undefined.84)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign memory location for your pointer `A`.

The following statement

```
int *A = NULL;
```

only states that A is a pointer to an integer and currently the address which it points to is NULL. Since writing to NULL and dereferencing NULL is undefined behavior, you are getting a segmentation fault.

You need to allocate memory using [malloc](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/) to solve the problem or make the pointer point to a valid object.

Comment: Making `A` point to any valid object would avoid the seg fault. For example: `int n; int *A = &n; *A = 12;` would work. `malloc` is not the only solution.

Comment: @Keith, Agreed. : ) Modified my answer slightly to reflect this.